# Squeezebox server on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, firewall, squeezebox

I want to run Squeezebox server on my Mac running OS 10.6 Snow Leopard. The Firewall settings on 10.6 now let you speciy by *Application* things that are allowed to connect through the firewall. But Squeezebox server isn't an application, so I can't select it.

If I turn the firewall off, it works fine. This is a reasonable step for a desktop (as it's always connecting to the 'net through the router's firewall) but on a laptop that connects via public WiFi it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is a way to do this, although I'd be nice if there was a better way. You can add command-line applications to that allowed by the Firewall settings, and as the Squeezebox server is just a Perl script, if you add /usr/bin/perl to the list of apps allowed, then it works ok.

When you go to add an Application to the list, you can't see the /usr directory listed, even from the root of the disk, so you have to symlink the /usr/bin directory to somewhere that is visible, and then you can navigate to the appropriate directory & select perl.exe. Once you've added perl.exe to the list, you can remove the symlink.

Comment: You need to use the Terminal.app from Applications/Utilities. In that enter

`ln -s /usr/bin link-to-usr-bin`

Which will create a link-to-usr-bin directory link in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to get this to work: in the firewall advanced settings dialog if you uncheck the 'Enable stealth mode' option then you should see it *ask* whether you want to add Perl to the list of apps allowed, rather than have to jump through the hoops of symlinking and adding it to the list manually.